# CLOSED CSS avoid inheritance for input in specific div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this for almost 2 days and i can't find rigthful help to answer my problem.
I hope you can help me :)

I've one master div with an ID ("myDiv") and a stylesheet who override input with specific properties. But, sometimes i'll like not to get the stylesheet specification.

In this exemple below, input1 need to receive the css specification but i want input2 and input3 to be clear. And if it's possible get there own.

I assume you understand it's a small sample from a bigger stylesheet =)

Exemple:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <input id="input1" />
   <div class="Picker">
       <input id="input2" />
       <div>
           <input id="input3" />
       </div> 
   </div>
   ... Other html markup
</div>
```

StyleSheet:

```
#myDiv input {
   width: 40%;
   border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
```

I tried this but it's not working at all ([:not documentation from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:not)):

```
#myDiv div:not(.Picker) input {
   width: 40%;
   border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
```

I tried something else (direct inheritance) :

```
#myDiv div:not(.Picker) > input {
   width: 40%;
   border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
```

Thank all for your attention.
Apologize for my bad english :)

Bobuche

Answer (score 2):

Not so clear if you need to match `#input1` or the other inputs

in the first case use

```
#myDiv input#input1 {
  ...
}
```

otherwise exclude the first input using `:not()`

```
#myDiv input:not(#input1) {
   ...
}
```

both these selectors have a higher specificity than `#myDiv input` so you will be able to override the properties defined.

Comment: I'll like input1 match the css but not input2 and input3.
I don't want to use input id just exclusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Exclusions are generally problematic. Here you would have to say "any input that's a child of `#myDiv` or any input descendant of a child of `#myDiv` other than `.Picker`". So

```
#myDiv > input, #myDiv > :not(.Picker) input { ... }
```

```css
#myDiv > input, #myDiv > :not(.Picker) input { 
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
   <label for="input1">input1: </label><input id="input1" />
   <div class="Picker">
       <label for="input2">input2: </label><input id="input2" />
       <div>
           <label for="input3">input3: </label><input id="input3" />
       </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="Something else">
       <label for="input4">input4: </label><input id="input4" />
       <div>
           <label for="input5">input5: </label><input id="input5" />
       </div> 
   </div>
   ... Other html markup
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly i'll like to match all descendant of div "myDiv" that is not in other element containing class ".Picker"

Comment: @Bobuche - You can't express that exactly in CSS selectors. You would need JS to select all such inputs and apply a class to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply CSS properties on input with id input1 you can simply select by using selector #input1
As id attribute is unique for each tag so it won't effect other html input tags.

```
#input1 {

}
```

And if you want tou apply CSS on input with ids input1 and input2 use either of the following ways

```
#input1,#input2{

}

.Picker input{

}
```